# How to print raw json object from file based off its ID Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a json file locally containing some data. I am writing a path so that when the user does /person/1 it will only return the raw json from the file for that person object, based off that ID.

```
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sally",
  "age": "12",
  "likes": [cats, dogs, rabbits]
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "jenny",
  "age": "22",
  "likes": [games, makeup]
  }
]
```

The idea is when the user goes localhost:8080/people/1 they would get returned onto the screen

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sally",
  "age": "12",
  "likes": [cats, dogs, rabbits]
  }
```

I tried using a PersonDTO and I could return everyone, and I know with some work I could filter that by ID, but I want the raw data, not the cleaner java/Spring Boot version which I get from doing it the DTO way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gson,try the below code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/people/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> getPeopleInfo(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id) throws Exception {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(new File("D:\\codes\\gitlab\\response.json"));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(reader, JsonNode.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonNode.size(); i++) {
        JsonNode element = jsonNode.get(i);
        if (element.get("id").asInt() == id) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(element, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: Works up until it's returned (checked via debug) then the page errors:


There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBoolean"])
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBoolean"])

Comment: Had to change getPersonInfo(int id) to (@PathVariable int id) to work with the path mapping

Comment: I change use fastjson